# Python set allowing addition of duplicate tuple coordinates and not recognizng tuples that are present for removal

Tags: python, duplicates, set, tuples, coordinates

I am using a set to hold the coordinates of cell centers of neighbor cells in a 3D cellular automata script of an evoloving topology. If a cell is a neighbor to two cells, I do not want it's center point to be stored twice.

Within a loop I am updating this set, both removing neighbor coordinates that are now being operated on, and adding new neighbors as my topology evolves. I have run into a curious issue when tuple entries in my set are not being recognized for removal or avoiding duplicate addition despite the removed/added tuple being identical to what exists in the set.

I am hoping someone has run into this before. I tried to replicate this with a demonstartion code, thinking it had something to do with me rounding numbers to 3 decmila places in order to allow for tupe coordinates to be recognized, however I could not recreate this issue in a short code to share. So, please see this output where you can see multiple duplicates (every coordinate entry is a tuple so its not a problem with inconsistent type):

```
print(type(neighbor_cells))
neighbor_cells

>> set
>> {(-163.592, -173.592, 485.0),
(-163.592, -123.592, 485.0),
 (-163.592, -123.592, 485.0),
 (116.408, -93.592, 485.0),
 (136.408, -73.592, 495.0),
 (86.408, -103.592, 485.0),
 (-173.592, 36.408, 485.0),
 (-173.592, 36.408, 485.0),
 (-43.592, 126.408, 485.0),
 (126.408, -73.592, 495.0),
 (46.408, 56.408, 475.0),
 (-153.592, 166.408, 495.0),
 (-53.592, 126.408, 485.0),
 (-53.592, 126.408, 485.0),
 (156.408, 66.408, 485.0),
 (86.408, -143.592, 485.0),
 (-123.592, -103.592, 475.0),
 (-103.592, -73.592, 485.0),
 (156.408, 56.408, 475.0),
 (126.408, 106.408, 485.0),
 (76.408, 106.408, 475.0),
 (66.408, 166.408, 475.0),
 (-143.592, 96.408, 475.0),
...}
```

I tried implementing the following to check if duplicates could be sort of manually identified but the following printed nothing:

```
for i,s in enumerate(list(neighbor_cells)):
    for j,q in enumerate(list(neighbor_cells)):
        if s == q: print(s)
```

**NOTES**

Thank you all for the suggestions! I know its not ideal to leave out the code but it was too long and convoluted to be of any use, I thought, and I could not write a sample code that would do the same thing. However, I noticed a couple things and found a jancky fix for this problem in a different sense.

If I ensured the coordinate added were tuples of np.array types, e.g. not lists, and were rounded to a fixed number of decimal places, I was able to find tuples in the set reliably.

Despite this fix and reliable searches for tuples in my sets, there was one set that would still not allow for exactly matching tuples to be found. After many attempts, I found that just making a string out of the coordinates before making the tuple worked for adding to the set and for querying from it. for example:

```
my_tuple = tuple(str(coord))
my_set.add(my_tuple)
check_tuple = tuple(str(check_coord))
check_tuple in my_tuple
```

Comment: Welcome to SOF ! Please add the code where you're adding items to the `set`

Comment: What NumPy version are you on?

Comment: Sets *do not allow duplicates*. It follows that your coordinates are not precise duplicates. But they are floating point values and one cannot reliably compare floats for equality. They may *look* rounded to 3 decimals is but that just how they are being displayed. Using `round()` does not produce exact rounded quantities, only the nearest representable float approximation.

Comment: Thank you all. I realized the issue was the data type of the values stored in the coordinate tuples in my set. I had these coordingtes coming in as 32-bit and 64-bit floats from different methods so depending on the float type the set would allow "duplicates" or not. I see now that these weren't true duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

No code to show you problem, I give one case for it, maybe its your case

```
class Coordinate(tuple):

    def __new__(cls, sequence):
        return tuple.__new__(cls, sequence)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '({:.3f}, {:.3f}, {:.3f})'.format(self[0], self[1], self[2])

point_1 = Coordinate((-163.592111, -123.592222, 485.592333))
point_2 = Coordinate((-163.592222, -123.592333, 485.592444))

lst = set((point_1, point_2))
```

it get the result

```
>>> lst
{(-163.592, -123.592, 485.592), (-163.592, -123.592, 485.592)}
```

For the result, it seems there are items with same values in set. Actually, they are different value, but shown the same.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I checked what I am putting into the set and each time is tuple of a numpy array that is rounded to 3 decimal places so I am confused why duplicates are being allowed if it is the same type from the same format going in each time.

Comment: So it's better have a code to show how you get the data and put them into set.

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful to see the code that you use to add the tuples to the set. However, I ran a simple experiment with the numbers you show, and my set did remove the duplicates. Without seeing your code, it's hard to tell why the set is not recognizing identical tuples as the same.

As a suggestion, when I ran my experiment I added the tuples to the set by first adding the tuple to a variable and then adding the set. I didn't add the tuple directly to the set.

```
t1 = (d1, d2, d3)
set.add(t1)
```

Also, I used `round()` to round the numbers when adding them to the tuples. Double-check the function and the place in the code where you are using it because it might be the reason why the set is seeing two identical tuples as different (both for duplicate removal and for tuple deletion).